# global integer assignment - lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am new to objective c and I am trying to change the value of a global integer in objective c but the compiler is complaining with the following message: "lvalue require as left operand of assignment".

Here is the line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate someNSIntegerValue] = myNSIntegerValue;
```

I am sure the answer to this is simple, so simple in fact that I cannot find an answer for what I am doing wrong.

Comment: whats up with the leading '**' ?

Comment: Anders K.: I think the questioner wanted to make it bold for some reason. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thomson Corner has already said, `someNSIntegerValue` is probably a getter. But even if it was not, what you are doing there can not possibly work, because it translates to this:

```
[someInstance someMethod] = someValue;
```

or in C

```
someFunction() = someValue;
```

This hopefully makes clear that its wrong. What you could try:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate setSomeNSIntegerValue: myNSIntegerValue];
```

Or the property-ish way (in case you @synthesize'd one):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.someNSIntegerValue = myNSIntegerValue;
```

**Note** that the last example should actually do the same as the one before that.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the property is `@synthesize`d; the property needs only to be declared in a header. You might even be able to do it without a `@property`, as long as the correct setter is declared explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`someNSIntegerValue` is the getter method for a property if that's what you put in your AppDelegate.  Try `setSomeNSIntegerValue` instead.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I created the property using @synthesize, am i still able to call setSomeNSIntegerValue?

Comment: Yup, creating properties with `@property` and `@synthesize` is how you use setSomeNSIntegerValue, as long as you don't set the property attribute to `readonly`.